# Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is missing the following properties from type in Typescript react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am getting some datatype error in typescript while getting first record of an array. I am initializing the data like  -

```
const ABData= testData.B.map(({ id, name }) => ({
        label: translateFn!(id),
        value : name
    }));

const newData: PropsInterface = {
        displayData: ABData[0]
    };
```

Below is my data -

```
export const testData: PropsInterface = {
    A: [
        { value: "All", key: "All" },
    ],
    B: [
        {id: "0", name: ""},
        {id: "100000008472", name: "Y6DC"}
    ],
    C: "100000008472",
    D: [{id: "0", name: "None"}],
    E: [
        {value: "", key: "None"},
        {value: "A", key: "Test"},
    ]

}
```

Here is my interface -

```
export interface PropsInterface {
    A: Array<First>;
    B: Array<Second>;
    C: string;
    D: Array<Second>;
    E: Array<First>;
}

export interface First{
    key: string;
    value: string;
}

export interface Second{
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I am getting error in displayData if I am trying to get first data using 0th index.

error is - `Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Second[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Did you try to put A, B, C, D and E as optional?

Comment: @kunquan I will be sending A, B , C, D, E data in props. So need to make it optional. The problem is from the typescript side I think.

Comment: Well I think the problem is that `PropsInterface` require all A, B, C, D and E  but `newData` only has A

Comment: @kunquan Yes I have sent all the data but right now I am getting error in B. So I have displayed only that data but yes I am already sending all the data i.e. A,B,C,D,E.

Answer (score 1):

First of all lets check your `PropsInterface`:

```js
// I made A, C, D optionals since the problem here is B as you say first
export interface PropsInterface {
  A?: Array<First>;
  B: Array<Second>;
  C?: string;
  D?: Array<Second>;
  E?: Array<First>;
}
```

Then you `First` and `Second` interfaces:

```js
export interface First {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface Second {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Now the data you are providing:

```js
export const testData: PropsInterface = {
  A: [{value: 'All', key: 'All'}],
  B: [
    {id: '0', name: ''},
    {id: '100000008472', name: 'Y6DC'}
  ],
  C: '100000008472',
  D: [{id: '0', name: 'None'}],
  E: [
    {value: '', key: 'None'},
    {value: 'A', key: 'Test'}
  ]
};
```

Till here, everything is ok but the problem comes in your `.map` function:

```js
const ABData = testData.B.map(({id, name}) => ({
  label: translateFn!(id),
  value: name,
}));
```

Lets talk in terms of the pure object. You are assigning a value of type `{label: string, value: string}[]` to the `ABData` variable. Then you are assigning `ABData` to `newData` which is of type `PropsInterface`. You are telling (to TS) that `newData` is of type `PropsInterface` but this interface doesn't have a `displayData` property.

```js
const newData: PropsInterface = {
  displayLabel: ABData[0],
};
```

So, lets change the name of `displayData` prop by `B`.

```js
const newData: PropsInterface = {
  B: ABData[0]
};
```

The error is gone but we still have a problem `Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Second[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)`. This is beacause we are assigning an element of an array and not the array itself. So lets change new data with the following:

```js
const newData: PropsInterface = {
  B: ABData
};
```

This error is gone but we have a new problem `Type '{ label: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Second[]'.`, so lets fix it. `Second` has `id` and `name` but we are trying to assign `label` and `value`. For this lets modify the `.map` function to this:

```js
const ABData = testData.B.map(({id, name}) => ({
  id: translateFn!(id),
  name: name,
}));
```

And thats it, we have fix all the errors. The final result is:

```js
export const testData: PropsInterface = {
  A: [{value: 'All', key: 'All'}],
  B: [
    {id: '0', name: ''},
    {id: '100000008472', name: 'Y6DC'}
  ],
  C: '100000008472',
  D: [{id: '0', name: 'None'}],
  E: [
    {value: '', key: 'None'},
    {value: 'A', key: 'Test'}
  ]
};

export interface PropsInterface {
  A?: Array<First>;
  B: Array<Second>;
  C?: string;
  D?: Array<Second>;
  E?: Array<First>;
}

export interface First {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface Second {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const ABData = testData.B.map(({id, name}) => ({
  id: translateFn!(id),
  name: name
}));

const newData: PropsInterface = {
  B: ABData
};
```

Comment: I agree with your point, But I want to pass only first data of array i.e. B: ABData[0]. So How can I achieve this. I don't wanna pass whole array, I just wanna pass first data of an array.

Comment: In this case you can change the `B` property of your `PropsInterface` to `B: Second` instead of using an array. In case you want to keep the use of the array then you can be tricky and do `B: [ABData[0]]` in `newData` assignment thus you will keep the use of `Second[]` and assign only the first element of `ABData`